# NSString Array to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray saved to my server and when I return it via this code:

```
[AsyncURLConnection request:url completeBlock:^(NSData *data) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if (![myString isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myString] forKey:@"savedArray"];
            NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedArray"]];
            contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
                [table reloadData];
            }else{
                contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }

        });
    });
} errorBlock:^(NSError *errorss) {

}];
```

oldSavedArray array returns:

```
 (
    (
    "Andrew Dunn",
    "andrew@dunn-carabali.com",
    accept
),
    (
    "John Appleseed",
    "John-Appleseed@mac.com",
    alert
)
)
```

But

```
 contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
```

always bombs out with

```
-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have tried every possible method I can think of to get this right, so I am confused on what to do next or how I can save the NSMutableArray to my server so that a member can retrieve it when they login or use a different device, with out wasting database space.

Answer (score 3):

First off, why do you have two nested dispatch_async calls like that?  This appears to accomplish nothing.  Skip the outer one and just use the inner dispatch_async.

Second, on this line...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myString] forKey:@"savedArray"];
```

You are storing a string (myString) in the user defaults.  Then the on the line below it...

```
NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedArray"]];
```

You are pulling that exact same string out of the user defaults and assigning it to an array.  So "oldSavedArray" is not an NSArray, it's an NString.  And NSString does not have a "count" selector.

UPDATE:

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but I'm guessing you want to decode some JSON data from your server (which should contain an array) and store it in user defaults.  If that is the case, here is an example of how to do that:

```
if (![myString isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * arrayFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    if (!arrayFromJSON) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't decode JSON, error: %@ (userInfo: %@)", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {
        NSParameterAssert([arrayFromJSON isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]); // consider improving your code to handle unexpected data.  If your server were to start returning something besides an array your code is going to break
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayFromJSON] forKey:@"savedArray"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this better.

Comment: Please see my update--and if it doesn't help, you probably need to explain what your intent is.